# iCalendar / .ics - Differences on Outlook (Windows), Outlook (Android), Calendar (IOS), Google Calendar (Web)

Tags: icalendar

The following iCal data is displayed differently in calendars on iOS, Android and Windows. For example, "Appointment #1" is displayed correctly from 10:00 to 11:00 in the iOS calendar. It is also displayed correctly in the Google web calendar. However, in Outlook on Windows, the appointment is displayed from 11:00 to 12:00. It is also displayed incorrectly in the Google Calendar app. What could be the reason for this?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:TerminApp//DevXY
REFRESH-INTERVAL;VALUE=DURATION:PT5M
METHOD:PUBLISH
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-MICROSOFT-CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:TerminApp
X-WR-CALDESC:Deine Termine aus dem Terminplaner
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
X-WR-RELCALID:mail@mail.com
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT5M
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011028T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010325T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:123456789a
LOCATION:Hamburg
SUMMARY:Appointment #1
DESCRIPTION:Hier steht die Beschreibung
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230919T100000Z
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230919T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20230901T170000Z
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:123456789b
LOCATION:Hamburg
SUMMARY:Appointment #2
DESCRIPTION:Hier steht die Beschreibung 2
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230919T130000Z
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230919T140000Z
DTSTAMP:20230901T170000Z
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:123456789c
LOCATION:Hamburg
SUMMARY:Appointment #3
DESCRIPTION:Hier steht die Beschreibung 3
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230920T100000Z
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230920T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20230901T170000Z
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I tested on iOS, Android and Windows.